# Can someone help me solve this logarithmic integral composed of trigonometric functions?

Tags: integration

So, the integral in question is this:
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\ln\left(\frac{(R^2-a^2\sin^2\theta)^{1/2} + a\cdot\cos\theta}{(R^2-a^2\sin^2\theta)^{1/2} - a\cdot \cos\theta}\right)\cos(\theta) d\theta$$
I need an analytical solution in terms of a, and R (they're both real and positive constants).
I have tried with Wolfram Alpha but it doesn't seem to understand it.
If someone can guide me, i have no idea where to start.

Comment: Mathematica gives $\frac{4\sqrt{R^2-a^2}\left(K\left(\frac{a^2}{R^2}\right)-E\left(\frac{a^2}{R^2}\right)\right)}{a\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{R^2}}}$, where $K$ and $E$ are the complete elliptic integral of the first kind and incomplete elliptic integral of the second kind respectively.

Comment: However, if $a>R$, the imaginary part of Mathematica’s expression seems to be off from numerical integration by some rational multiple of $\pi i$ that I am currently unable to express in terms of $R$ and $a$.

Comment: @KStarGamer. I have a problem with your answer (I was not able to get it at university - only version 8; with Wolfram Cloud, it aborts for time limitations). Using $R=k a$, you nice formula gives  $4 k \left(K\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)-E\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)\right)$. For $k=2$ this gives $1.74631$ while numerical integration gives $2.23267$. Could you check ? Thanks & cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Hmm for me the numerical integration agrees and gives $1.74631$ with $a=2$ and $k=2$.

Comment: @KStarGamer. Are you meaning $k=2$ and $a=1$ ?

Comment: @KStarGamer. I did not "see" that the integral changed  (I am blind). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Please, when you receive an answer but later you change the problem, alert the answerer. I wasted hours with the initial integral.

Answer (score 1):

**This is an answer to the initial question in which the last cosine was not present.**

I do not know if there is a closed form solution for this integral but we can do a few things for approximations.

First, let $R=k\,a$ with, for sure, $k >1$
$$\int_{-\frac \pi 2}^{+\frac \pi 2}\log \left(\frac{\sqrt{R^2-a^2 \sin ^2(t)}+a \cos (t)}{\sqrt{R^2-a^2 \sin ^2(t)}-a
   \cos (t)}\right)\,dt=\int_{-\frac \pi 2}^{+\frac \pi 2}\log \left(\frac{\sqrt{k^2-\sin ^2(t)}+\cos (t)}{\sqrt{k^2-\sin ^2(t)}-\cos
   (t)}\right)\,dt$$ Expand the integrand as a series around $t=0$
$$\log \left(\frac{\sqrt{k^2-\sin ^2(t)}+\cos (t)}{\sqrt{k^2-\sin ^2(t)}-\cos
   (t)}\right)=\log \left(\frac{k+1}{k-1}\right)+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac {P_n(k)}{(2n)! \, k^{2n-1} }\,t^{2n}$$ I let you finding the polynomials in $k$. Integrating termwise is not a problem.

Just to give a taste, for $k=2$ and using only  $\sum_{n=1}^5$ the result, converted to decimals, is $2.23290$ while  numerical integration gives
$2.23267$. Doing the same for $k=10$, this gives $0.401568$ while  numerical integration gives $ 0.401566$

**Edit**

Another possibility could be to write
$$\color{red}{f(t)}=\log \left(\frac{\sqrt{k^2-\sin ^2(t)}+\cos (t)}{\sqrt{k^2-\sin ^2(t)}-\cos(t)}\right)=\log \left(\frac{k+1}{k-1}\right)+\sum_{n=1}^p c_n \,t^{2n}=\color{red}{g(t)}$$ and to identify the $c_n$'s matching the  derivative values at $t=0$ and $t=\frac \pi 2$. For $f(t)$, they are quite simple
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \text{derivative} & t=0 & t=\frac \pi 2 \\
 f^{(1)}(t) & 0 & -\frac{2}{\sqrt{k^2-1}} \\
 f^{(2)}(t) & -\frac{2}{k} & 0 \\
 f^{(3)}(t) & 0 & \frac{2 k^2}{\left(k^2-1\right)^{3/2}} \\
 f^{(4)}(t) & \frac{2 \left(k^2-3\right)}{k^3} & 0 \\
 f^{(5)}(t) & 0 & -\frac{2 k^2 \left(k^2+8\right)}{\left(k^2-1\right)^{5/2}} \\
 f^{(6)}(t) & -\frac{2 \left(k^4-30 k^2+45\right)}{k^5} & 0
\end{array}
\right)$$

Using the conditions at $t=0$ gives
$$c_1=-\frac{1}{k} \qquad\qquad c_2=\frac{k^2-3}{12 k^3}\qquad\qquad c_3=-\frac{k^4-30 k^2+45}{360 k^5}$$
The other coefficients, derived from the conditions at $t=\frac \pi 2$ are too long to be typed here but they are simply obtained (a system of linear equations).

For $p=6$, some results

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 1.5 & 3.3256459 & 3.3257847 \\
 2.0 & 2.2326698 & 2.2326746 \\
 2.5 & 1.7111111 & 1.7111087 \\
 3.0 & 1.3954049 & 1.3954032 \\
 3.5 & 1.1811528 & 1.1811518 \\
 4.0 & 1.0253233 & 1.0253228 \\
 4.5 & 0.9065185 & 0.9065182 \\
 5.0 & 0.8127722 & 0.8127720 \\
 5.5 & 0.7368248 & 0.7368248 \\
 6.0 & 0.6739988 & 0.6739988 
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Now, the problem is totally different with**
$$\int_{-\frac \pi 2}^{+\frac \pi 2}\log \left(\frac{\sqrt{k^2-\sin ^2(t)}+\cos (t)}{\sqrt{k^2-\sin ^2(t)}-\cos
   (t)}\right)\,\cos(t)\,dt=4 k \left(K\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)-E\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)\right)$$ @KStarGamer gave in comments.

In fact, we even have the antiderivative
$$2 k
   \left(F\left(t\left|\frac{1}{k^2}\right.\right)-E\left(t\left|\frac{1}{k^2}\right.
   \right)\right)+\sin (t) \log \left(\frac{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{2 k^2+\cos (2 t)-1}+2 \cos (t)}{\sqrt{2}
   \sqrt{2 k^2+\cos (2 t)-1}-2 \cos (t)}\right)$$
For the definite integral, a simple but quite accurate approximation could be
$$\frac \pi k\,\,\frac {1-\frac{61}{80 }t+\frac{121}{1920}t^2 } {1-\frac{91}{80 }t +\frac{49}{192}t^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^{11}}\right)\qquad \text{with} \qquad t=\frac 1 {k^2}$$

Comment: What has happened to the factor $\cos(\theta)$ in the integrand?

Comment: @JanG. The initial question did not include the last term ! I shall edit.